# PHP сравнить расхождение многомерных ассоциативных массивов

Tags: php, массивы

Есть два массива. Один хранится в базе, второй прилетает через определенный промежуток ответом на запрос от API. Необходимо сравнивать массивы и выводить их расхождения. Например в базе лежит массив:

```
$old_data = [
    ['name'  => 'name1', 'value' => '123'],
    ['name'  => 'name2', 'value' => '456'],
    ['name'  => 'name3', 'value' => '789'],
];
```

Нам прилетает новый массив, в котором есть некоторые отличия:

```
$new_data = [
    ['name'  => 'name1', 'value' => '321'], // value изменился
    ['name'  => 'name2', 'value' => '456'],
    ['name'  => 'name3', 'value' => '789'],
    ['name'  => 'name4', 'value' => '999'], // новый элемент
    ['name'  => 'name5', 'value' => '000'], // новый элемент
];
```

Нужно сформировать результирующий массив в котором будут три элемента name1, name5, name6

Сразу в голову приходит array_diff, типа как-то так:

```
foreach ($new_data as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($old_data[$key])){ 
        $diff = array_diff($value, $old_data[$key]);
    } else {
        /// тут обрабатываем новые элементы, например добавляем их в результирующий массив diff
    }
}
```

Но это уже какой-то велосипед. Может есть более элегантное решение поиска такого расхождения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну на самом деле, ничего велосипедного лично я не вижу (видали и похуже).

Если для `$diff` и для `/// тут обрабатываем новый...` - одинаковые действия, то как вариант можно предложить:

```
$diff = array_filter($new_data, function ($element) use (&$old_data) {
    return !in_array($element, $old_data);
});
var_dump($diff);
```

Либо-же типа такого:

```
$diff = array_udiff( $old_data, $new_data, function ($a, $b) { return $a != $b; } );
var_dump($diff);
```

**P.S.1.** Не уверен что мои варианты оптимальнее вашего, оставляйте свой **:)**

**P.S.2.** Если будете брать мои варианты, то стоит тщательнее затестить эти функции, не уверен что они могут работать как надо.

Comment: Ваш вариант работает, только есть один момент - если в новом массиве пришло элементов меньше чем в старом (мой пример, только наоборот), то такие элементы в вашей функции игнорируются.

Comment: @user137 эти 2 функции по разному реагируют на ваш случай, проверьте и второй пример :) Может он тот, который вам нужен.

Comment: Если поменять массивы местами (т.е. имитировать ситуацию когда нам прилетел ответ с меньшим количеством элементов чем есть в массиве $old_data) Ваша вторая функция просто возвращает весь массив.

Comment: @user137 к сожалению я вас плохо понимаю, не могу понять что не так. Можете дополнить ответ примером: первый массив, второй массив и что ждете увидеть на выходе.

Comment: Некорректно сформулировал, прошу прощения. Ваша функция работает - возвращает массивы которые отличаются, мне же необходимо найти не только их но и расхождения в value. Например, в моем первом сообщении было у name1 значение value 123, в новом массиве значение 321, нужно вычислить разницу: 321-123 = 189. name4 и name5 не было в старом массиве - значит возвращаем просто их значения.
А может быть ситуация когда элемент name1 был в старом массиве а в новом его нет - это тоже расхождение, его нужно обработать, в нашем случае возвращаем value с отрицательным знаком

Comment: @user137 яб сделал тогда через `foreach` если вы не знаете как, тогда создайте новую темку и мы попробуем вам помочь

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/848064/
)

Comment: @user137 вижу, щас что нибудь придумаем.