# Расхождение значений в многомерном ассоциативном массиве

Tags: php, массивы

Дано два массива. Первый лежит в базе и называется `$old_data`.
Выглядит так:

```
$old_data = [
    ['name'  => 'name1', 'value' => '123'],
    ['name'  => 'name2', 'value' => '456'],
];
```

По API нам приходит новый массив такой же структуры но с другим количеством элементов их может быть **больше либо меньше** чем в предыдущем массиве и предыдущие значения могут повторяться.
Например:

```
$new_data = [
    ['name'  => 'name1', 'value' => '321'], //изменилось значение
    ['name'  => 'name2', 'value' => '456'], // ничего не поменялось
    ['name'  => 'name4', 'value' => '999'], // новый элемент    
];
```

Необходимо найти расхождение значений `value`, то есть конкретно в этом примере результирующий массив должен иметь вид:

```
$diff= [
        ['name'  => 'name1', 'value' => '198'], // 321 из new - 123 из old
        ['name'  => 'name4', 'value' => '999'], // новый элемент предыдущего значения не было, просто выводим   
    ];
```

Если в новом массиве у нас пришло меньше элементов чем в старом, то `value` соответственно будет с минусом.
С помощью какой конструкции можно было бы сделать такой вывод? Через два `foreach`?

Comment: не понял как вы из 321 и 123 получили 189 (или надо было 198?), и про минус. Если `name` уникальные то делайте их ключами (`array_column()`), и потом манипулируйте с массивами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как всегда, не рассчитываю на оптимальность и рациональность, но задачу, вроде как, решает:

```
$old_data = [
    ['name'  => 'name1', 'value' => '123'],
    ['name'  => 'name2', 'value' => '456'],
    ['name'  => 'name5', 'value' => '456'],
];

$new_data = [
    ['name'  => 'name1', 'value' => '321'],
    ['name'  => 'name2', 'value' => '456'],
    ['name'  => 'name4', 'value' => '999'],
];

//  Приведем массивы в нормальный вид
$new_array = [];
array_walk($old_data, function ($item, $key) use (&$new_array) {
    $new_array[$item['name']] = (int)$item['value'];
    // Если значения в 'name' могут повторяться, 
    // то удаляем строчку выше и раскомментируем кусок:
    //if (isset($new_array[$item['name']])) {
    //  $new_array[$item['name']] += (int)$item['value'];
    //}else{
    //  $new_array[$item['name']] = (int)$item['value'];
    //}
    // Ниже сделать тоже самое
});
$old_data = $new_array;
$new_array = [];
array_walk($new_data, function ($item, $key) use (&$new_array) {
    $new_array[$item['name']] = (int)$item['value'];
});
$new_data = $new_array;

//  Формируем общий массив
foreach ($old_data as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($new_data[$key])) {
        if ($new_data[$key] == $value) {
            unset($new_data[$key]);
        } else {
            $new_data[$key] -= $value;
        }
    }else{
        $new_data[$key] = -$value;
    }
}

//  Возвращаем как было
$diff = array();
array_walk($new_data, function ($item, $key) use (&$diff) {
    $diff[] = ['name' => $key, 'value' => (string)$item];    
});

// Любуемся
var_dump($diff);
```

Comment: Старое доброе замечание гласит: пока не заметишь реального недостатка в решении, не лезь оптимизировать.

Comment: @Other та просто я заметил что многие другие люди тут у нас профи, постоянно им что-то не нравится, неудобно перед ними за нубятсво мое, приходится оправдываться.

Comment: Я не проводил ревью Вашего решения, так что не все сразу критики :) Не надо писать "я новичок" или подобное - профи и сами это поймут по коду, а нубам это вообще до лампочки.

Answer (score 0):

как вариант решения задачи

```
$src = array_column($old_data, 'value', 'name');

$res = array_filter(array_map(function($v) use ($src){
            $k = $v['name'];

            if(!array_key_exists($k ,$src)){}
            elseif( $v['value'] == $src[$k] ){ $v = null; }
            else {  $v['value'] -= $src[$k]; }
            return $v;

        }, $new_data));
```